# Let A be a positive definite matrix and G be semi positive definite matrix. Is (A+G) positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be positive definite tridiagonal matrix with positive e-values and G be a semi-positive definite diagonal matrix with non negative e-values.

I need to proove that (A+G) is invertible matrix. What can we say about the evalues of (A+G)? Should we proove that (A+G) is positive definite?

I am looking for a more elegant proof than the:

$x^{T} (A+G)x >0$

Comment: In what way do you think checking $\min_{||x||=1} x^T (A+G) x>0$ is not elegant? One easily has $\min_{||x||=1} x^T (A+G) x \geq \min_{||y||=1} y^T A y+\min_{||z||=1} z^T G z>0$ since $A$ is positive definite and $G$ is PSD. There are probably other ways to approach it, but its hard for me to guess what you would consider elegant if this one line proof is not.

Comment: Your proof is super elegant but why the first part of your inequality holds?

Comment: Pick $x_*$ which minimizes $x^T (A+G)x$ subject to $\|x\|=1$. Then you have $(x_*)^T(A+G)x_*=(x_*)^T A x_* + (x_*)^T G x_*$. You then also have $(x_*)^T A x_* > \min_{\|y\|=1} y^T A y > 0$ since $\|x_*\|=1$ and similarly for $G$. Taking this approach you could also just argue that $(x_*)^T A x_* >0$ since $A \succ 0$ and $(x_*)^T G x_* \geq 0$ since $G \succeq 0$, which is probably simpler once you have introduced $x_*$.

Comment: There is a small typo in my previous comment but it looks like I am no longer able to edit it. In any case it should say $(x_*)^T A x_* \geq \min_{\|y\|=1} y^T A y$ instead of $(x_*)^T A x_* > \min_{\|y\|=1} y^T A y$